# Is it possible to dynamically show the title and legend of an Echart for when the download icon is clicked?

Tags: vuejs2, echarts

[Echart reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwcmb.png)

My issue is that we are using custom components for our legend and title but when a user downloads a chart these are missing since they are not in the actual Echart.

Is it possible to use the title and legend of the Echart for only when the saveAsImage toolbox feature is clicked?